# Play sound with delay

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

Is it possible to play sound with delay ?for example play sound and repeat it after 40seconds and repeat again

Answer (score 0):

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:40.0 target:self selector:@selector(playSound:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

That will call the `playSound:` method every 40 seconds. If you'd rather wait exactly 40 seconds **after** the sound completes to start it again, you'll need to register a callback via `AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion` or whatever API you're using to play the sound, and create a non-repeating timer in the callback function.

Then too, you could use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` to avoid the explicit use of timers.